# ASP.NET/SQL Server hosting

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, host

I'm looking for an ASP.NET and SQL Server host for a site I'm developing. Here's the important caveat though: I have a backup of a SQL database (.bak file) and need to be able to restore this database on the host.

Can someone refer me to a host where I have enough control over SQL Server that I can restore a database .bak file?

Comment: https://www.gearhost.com works perfectly fine for my projects. I use their Free plan for development and scale to paid for production if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [CrystalTech](http://crystaltech.com/) lets you use SQL Management Studio to manage you database.
I've used it in the past and they have great customer support.

[Softsys Hosting](http://softsyshosting.com/Win08Hosting.aspx) also offers Management Studio access.

You can probably do restore from backup if they allow Management Studio access, right? I haven't tried myself, but I assume you can.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for--Management Studio access.

Answer (score 6):

I will recommend [AccuWebHosting.Com](https://www.accuwebhosting.com/). I've been with them for 4 years now.
With the control panel - WebsitePanel, you can easily restore .bak (SQL backup files).

You can refer to this article about how to backup your SQL database using WebsitePanel.

http://www.websitepanel.net/documentation/users-guide/sql-server-databases/#BackingupandRestoringSQLServerDatabase

Answer (score 4):

[Gearhost.com](http://gearhost.com) allows you SQL Server Management Studio access. You need to get the dedicated server to be able to restore and backup your server yourself; otherwise you'll need to submit a ticket for them to do it.  Their average response time from ticket inception to completion is about one hour (from experience).

Comment: Just to clarify you can do this all now via our control panel. No need to open a ticket. We also include an API and client CMD app which allows you to auto backup your databases as well to your computer.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.discountasp.net/ should do the trick.

SQL Hosting specifics: http://www.discountasp.net/sp_sqlhosting.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should give [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/) a look. It's free to get started, and while we don't currently provide the ability to restore back-up files, we have created a [tool that uses SQL Server Bulk Copy](https://github.com/appharbor/AppHarbor-SqlServerBulkCopy) to copy data fairly quickly.

(disclaimer, I'm co-founder of [AppHarbor](https://appharbor.com/))

Answer (score 1):

For Windows and MS SQL Server hosting, I use [OpenHosting](http://openhosting.com). Their SQL installs are complete, and you'd have access to the Management Studio to pull your restore, just as if it was a dedicate box.

Answer (score 0):

You can restore backups at [webhost4life](http://www.WebHost4Life.com/default.asp?refid=jongalloway). Can you explain why you need to restore a backup? A lot of the time you can just script your schema+data and run the script on the server.

Comment: It's because I have three tables with a combined 30K records or so I need to load into the database. I'm not SQL pro so I don't know any other way to get these records in there w/o doing a backup and restore.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Management Studio won't allow you to restore database from a local file. The backup file should be accessible by SQL Server - this normally means that backup file should reside on the SQL Server itself.

[Softsys Hosting](http://www.softsyshosting.com/) allows you to upload your backup file though (using DotNetPanel). You can even zip it, to conserve traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I would second webhost4life, i been with them less then a year, but it's been great.
It is also allows you to take database backups and restore, manage it trough sql management studio, good customer service, and very fast servers.

I am running with them my personal web forum (around 1k users and growing) and so far they been very good experience for me.

Heard many good things about CrystalTech as well